# Deploy Laravel project on DreamHost server

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am trying to deploy a Laravel (v 5.3) project on the DreamHost server (PHP v 5.5.38).

When I try an artisan command, I get

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', 
  expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE)
  in /home/laravelProjectName/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 475
```

Help?

Comment: Clarify wording; make format nicer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need PHP version >= 5.6.4. The helpers uses the splat operator (a.k.a. scatter operator):

```
function name(...$args) {}
```

This allows you to capture an unlimited number of variables passed as arguments to the function.

```
name(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: your answer is correct but now the problem is, i created php file for showing phpinfo(), its gave me a php version as  5.6.24 but when i run command on terminal for php version showing me as 5.5.38. Why? Because of this i am unable to run artisan commands.

Comment: @A.D you should ask your hosting provider. It's possible that Apache uses one version of PHP and the cli uses another one.

Comment: @ TheFallen Thanks for you help. Now i have successfully deployed my laravel project. But now i am getting new error **[PDOException]  could not find driver**. I know that i have to install php mysql_pdo but dont know how to do it on dreamhost shared server. Help?

Comment: @A.D the hosting should provide this out of the box. You probably have to enable it from the cPanel, if not ask the for assistance.